# What is known about Pathions, Chingons, Routons and Voudons?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers

It is well known that the quaternions, octonions, and sedenions are well studied, but I don't find any articles or books in which other hypercomplex numbers are studied. Does anyone know a book or an article in which other hypercomplex numbers are studied? And if so, what is the usage of numbers like **pathions**, **voudons**, etc...?

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the photo?

Comment: I guess this gives more context, although not much: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993448/omegath-iteration-of-cayley-dickson-construction.

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number#Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction

Comment: Nobody cares that much after $\mathbb{S}$.  They provide no usefulness to other branches of mathematics.

Comment: As said implicitly by @user10354138 : the more you advance in this chain, the more extremely bare are these spaces. No mathematics to eat there ; Not worth the value to spend time on them.

Comment: The photo has a huge mistake. It has Real numbers as a subset of Complex numbers (and other Hypercomplex numbers as well). But we know that while Real numbers and the other number sets together make all the numbers, they don't have anything in common. So Real numbers should be outside of them.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Just write "hypercomplex numbers" in Google search. The picture is the first thing you see.

Comment: @SnackExchange No, there's no mistake in the photo: modulo set-theoretic subtleties which aren't of interest here, we do indeed have $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and so on (e.g. $r=r+0i$).

Comment: If you want to know about hyperciomplex numbers, why did you pick a construction that has the least properties if numbers (even not associative)?

Comment: @JeanMarie but they are well-advertised.

Answer (score 5):

After a quick search on Math Sci Net, I have found:

- 1.229 articles containing the word "octonion"
- 56 articles containing the word "sedenion"
- 0 articles containing the word "pathion"
- 0 articles containing the word "chingon"
- 0 articles containing the word "routon"
- 1 article containing the word "voudon", whose author is named Voudon, Benoît

(this search includes title, abstract, and names of the authors).

---

**Edit.** If you type "Cayley-Dickson", these are the references with the highest number of citations according to Math Sci Net:

[image]

Comment: Also, I have found an article that mentions these algebras beyond the sedenions. They are called $2^n$-ions: https://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0207003 It is nearly the only article I found that contains the word "pathion" on Arxiv (there is another one by the same authors).The article is not on Math Sci Net and I don't know if that was peer-reviewed, this is why I did not find it with my previous search. If you really want to find something, you should search on Google Scholar.

Comment: John Baez is an excellent reference, not only on sedenions : all his writings are remarkable.

Comment: Here is another (in 2006): https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603281.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You can derive the sets of numbers using the *[Cayley–Dickson Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction)*. Algebras produced by this process are known as [Cayley–Dickson Algebras](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cayley-Dickson_algebra)  and these are better studied aka you can find more about them under *Cayley–Dickson Algebras*.

In addition, the names after the complex numbers are linked to numbers in latin, which in the graphic does not apply to those wich come after Sedenions. Normally the continuation would be *Sedenion ($16$-ions) $\to$ Trigintaduonions / Tricenibinions  ($32$-ions) $\to$ Sexageniquaternions / Sexagintaquaternions ($64$-ions)* $\to \dots$... (there are multible similar names for this and some of them are not even numbers - see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/234621) for more)

You will find much more with these more often used names.

---

---

Depending on the definition, there are many more such hypercomplex numbers. In the following, by hypercomplex numbers I only mean the numbers that can be created using the Cayley–Dickson construction (for the real numbers) and I will write their set as $\mathbb{\tilde{C}}$.

#### Applications

Actual applications of hypercomplex numbers with dimension above $16$ (on your graph adter $\mathbb{S}$) in the natural sciences are rare, but there are some in mathematics, e.g. in [Hypercomplex Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_analysis) or proves.

##### In Mathematics

**Hypercomplex Analysis**: There is the field in mathematics called *Hypercomplex Analysis*, which deals with the study of functions with arguments in $\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$.

- (**reference**:) A book on that matter is *Hypercomplex Analysis: New Perspectives and Applications* by *Swanhild Bernstein*, *Uwe Kähler*, *Irene Sabadini* and *Frank Sommen*, which does not deal directly with these sets of numbers, but works a lot with Clifford algebras, which in turn can be used to form these sets. So far I've only seen uses in mathematics in the book (for the sets of numbers), but I haven't read through it yet.

**Geometry**

In geometry you could use them to represent spaces / objects (points, vectors, ...) in $D > 16$. With a lot of work, it might be possible to represent the movement of a point around an axis in this space by a certain angle, which might be helpful in some theoretical model of physics, after all, hypercomplex numbers usually have representations as vectors and matrices.

From this, geometric properties could be derived (e.g. Euler's formula for these sets of numbers) with which proofs for geometric relationships and analysis analogous to the sedenions could be led, which could be used in such a theoretical model in physics.

**Calculus**

In calculus, certain differential equations could be solved or certain operations could be carried out. An example would be differential operators of hypercomplex order or solving describing movements of objects in spaces in $D > 16$. But the whole thing would really only have a use in mathematics.

**Hypercomplex Algebra**

Equations can be constructed which do not have solutions in $\mathbb{S}$, but in the larger sets that follow.

- $x^{2} = -1$ has no real solution but two complex ones: $x \in \left\{ -i,\, i \right\} \in \mathbb{C}$
- $x \cdot i = -i \cdot x \ne 0$ has not complex solution but in $\mathbb{H}$: $x \in \left\{ a \cdot j,\, a \cdot k \mid a \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \in \mathbb{H}$
- $x \cdot \left( j \cdot \left( k \right) \right) \ne \left( \left( x \right) \cdot j \right) \cdot k$ has no solution in $\mathbb{H}$ but multible in $\mathbb{O}$ ones

...

---

##### In Physics

There are a few applications e.g. in quantum physics.

For example, the [Trigintaduonion Emanation Theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360458326_Chiral_trigintaduonion_emanation_leads_to_the_standard_model_of_particle_physics_and_to_quantum_matter) allows a mathematical description of certain physical constants with $32$-ions (and you can find some of them in the standard model of particle physics).

> The chiral trigintaduonion emanation described here gives a precise derivation for the mysterious physics constant $\alpha$ (the fine-structure constant) from the mathematical physics formalism providing maximal information propagation, with $\alpha$ being the maximal perturbation amount (a fractal limit), and $\pi$ being the maximum amount of overall imaginary component contributing to that maximal perturbation. - *Stephen Winters-Hilt* in *[Fiat Numero: Trigintaduonion Emanation Theory and its Relation to the Fine-Structure Constant $\alpha$, the Feigenbaum Constant $c^{\infty}$, and $\pi$](http://www.m-hikari.com/astp/astp2021/astp1-4-2021/p/winters-hiltASTP1-4-2021.pdf)*

$32$-ion spaces have some applications too:

> A new insight on the problem of the sub-quark movement and their interactions can be given by the concept of trigintaduonion space. - *Zihua Weng* in *[Compounding Fields and Their Quantum Equations in the Trigintaduonion Space](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.0136.pdf)*

---

#### Studies

There are some studies in certain areas of mathematics. For example, there is a proof that all numbers in $\tilde{C}$ continue to have the property of power associativity.

Since calculating in $\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$ can be quite tiring if you constantly have such long formulas, there are also some algorithms for calculating in $\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$, e.g. *[An algorithm for multiplication of trigintaduonions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267097033_An_algorithm_for_multiplication_of_trigintaduonions)* by *Aleksandr Cariow* and *Galina Cariowa*.

For more precise or specific answers or references, a second question would probably be good.

Comment: I will not be more explicit. I will just say: when citing a paper, always check the journal on which the paper has been published. And in general, be careful about predatory journals and publishers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_publishing  , https://beallslist.net/ , https://www.rxcomms.com/blog/6-ways-spot-predatory-journal

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thanks for the tip. I looked at the individual references again and don't see anything particularly suspicious: I hardly have anything to complain about in the book, I use Research Gate often, arXiv doesn't have its own peer reviews, which can be a problem, and m-Hikari also checks works for plagiarism and the paper itself seems fine to me. So where is the problem?

Comment: Mhh... The reason I do not want to be explicit is because I don't want to make any claims about anything that is not even close to my research field. But, say, have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1711 , especially the abstract and formula (1)

Answer (score 2):

These terms are ad-hoc names for higher Cayley-Dickson algebras after the sedenions, however they are introduced in a formal mathematical paper published by ArXiv in 2002. These terms most notably appear in a [*Maple* implementation](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/detail.aspx?id=35420&L=E) of hypercomplex numbers up to the 256-D case (the 9th Cayley-Dickson algebra). They are actually proposed by [Tony Smith](http://web.archive.org/web/20110425191752/https://www.valdostamuseum.org/hamsmith/Voudons.html) (for the voudons, the highest of the nine) and [Robert P.C. de Marrais](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0207003.pdf) (from 32-ions to the 128-ions).

| Sequence | Dimension | Name | Symbol | Etymology |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 32 | pathion | ℙ | for the "32 Paths" of Kabbalah |
| 6 | 64 | chingon |  | for the 64 Hexagrams of the I Ching |
| 7 | 128 | routon |  | after that legendary source of high-tech innovativeness, Route 128 of the "Massachusetts Miracle" that paralleled Silicon Valley's on the "Left Coast" of this country. |
| 8 | 256 | voudon |  | after the 256 deities of the Ifa pantheon of Voodoo or Voudon |

The reason why the author limited the common "un-Latinate" names to such higher hypercomplex number systems is to study Clifford algebras, which has uses in representing rotations in high-dimensional space, the periodicity theorem, and monstrous moonshine. The authors claimed that all higher hypercomplex number systems can be broken down into copies of "voudon" space.

De Marrais continued to use the word "pathion" and "chingon" in his further papers. The word "routon" and "voudon", however only appeared twice and thrice and are usually still called $2^7$-ions and $2^8$-ions respectively. His paper that introduces these terms has been cited by at least two other journals not authored by him, including *[In Defense of Octonions](https://prespacetime.com/index.php/pst/article/view/199)* by Jonathan J. Dickau.

## Source notes

- The de Marrais source is introduced in Page 7, the Tony Smith link is
  now dead